# RSS reader with desktop alerts

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

What is a good RSS reader for Ubuntu that features a desktop alert mechanism where the alerts include details of each update?

i.e. I want to use it to be notified of new Stack Overflow questions with a certain tag, so would want to see details of the questions, not just be alerted by a flashing light, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any RSS reader that can do that. But there are a few [apps](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/537/apps-for-ask-ubuntu) that alerts you about new messages and tags.